# mysql_real_escape_string deletes variable contents

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

OK guys, I'm having trouble with mysql_real_escape_string. It is a simple POST table with title and contents, which should in theory work fine (by me).

```
$db = new mysqli('...','...','...','...') or die ('error with connection');
$db->set_charset('utf8');

$title  = trim($_POST['title']);
$contents   = trim($_POST['contents']);

$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$contents = mysql_real_escape_string($contents);

$sql = "INSERT INTO posts SET title = '$title', contents = '$contents'";
$query = $db->query($sql);
```

I found when I place 'echo' before and after 'mysql_escape_string' like:

```
echo 'before' . $title;
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
echo 'after' . $title;
```

that it echoes the title on the "before" line, but on the "after" line it echoes blank $title.

Note: whan I use 'mysql_escape_string' instead (of real), it works fine (but I guess this is weaker protection).

Any ideas??
Thank you.

Comment: Why aren't you using prepared statements instead? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: id try using `mysqli_real_escape_string` since you're using mysqli.

Comment: What is in the title?

Comment: @castis - you should post that as the answer.

Comment: @castis -nop, using "mysqli" instead of "mysql" doesn't work, stil empty.. but thanks for idea

Comment: @uollaa You need to use the OOP variant of `mysqli_real_escape_string`, i.e., `$db->real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `title` is empty is because [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is returning `FALSE`.
This happened because it requires a MySQL connection to the database, you have MySQLi. From the docs,

`A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is returned`

The way to fix the issue is to use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to match your database connection, as suggested in the other answers. Obviously for security, you're better off using prepared statements.

Also, the database link needs to be supplied. Since you're using the OO style, this is done as

```
$db = new mysqli()
$title = $db->real_escape_string($title)
```

Comment: You need to supply your database link - do 
`$db->real_escape_string($title)`

Comment: Thank you, this one works: $title = $db->real_escape_string($title)

Answer (score 2):

[mysql_real_escape_string()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) works in context of connection made by "mysql" extension, but you use "mysqli".

You need to either connect using mysql_connect() **not recommended**

Or you need to use new approaches from mysqli such as prepared statements or [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: OK, this seams to work, I found in the provided link, this line of code:

$city = $mysqli->real_escape_string($city);

(of course, modified it to my variables)

Answer (score 0):

You should not interpolate user-generated strings into sql. Use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

In your case:

```
$db = new mysqli('...','...','...','...') or die ('error with connection');
$db->set_charset('utf8');

$title  = trim($_POST['title']);
$contents   = trim($_POST['contents']);

$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title, contents) VALUES (?,?)");
$sql->bind_param('ss', $title, $contents);
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: You don't need the quotes around the placeholders